# MIPS/Assembly: How do I find register value by hand after an instruction is executed?

Tags: assembly, mips, instructions

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I have an instruction to find the content of a register after an executed instruction. The instruction:

add $s1, $s5, $t9

Register $s1 contents before the instruction: 0x00000457

How would I go about doing this by hand?

I know the instruction converted into binary is (based on register numbers, which is probably wrong. But I tried it considering I had no values):

```
0000 0010 1011 1000 1000 1000 0010 0000
```

But I don't really understand how to figure out what the value after that instruction would be.

Comment: What are the values in registers `$s5` and `$t9`?

Comment: @JakeHolzinger This is the only information I've been given. I know the register numbers for $s5 and $t9, but we're given no values within those registers. The answer to this problem is 0x0000ff3a, but I haven't a clue how to get there.

Comment: Perhaps the values of `$s5` and `$t9` came from a previous question? The result of the `add $s1, $s5, $t9` instruction depends on the values of those registers. You can't say that the result is always 0x0000ff3a.

Comment: @RaymondChen That's exactly what's been confusing me. I know how to do the problem with values, but I was never taught you could do it without them - and assumed the previous value given to me had some sort of merit for what the other two registers must be. Thank you for verifying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$s1` is the write-only destination for `add $s1, $s5, $t9`.  It does

```
$s1 = $s5 + $t9
```

The starting value of `$s1` is completely irrelevant and tells you nothing; the instruction has no dependency on it.

You need the values of the source operands, `$s5` and `$t9`.

Comment: Thank you Peter. This is what I thought, so I'm happy I'm not crazy. Looks to be a typo on my instructors end for not providing us values. I can do this problem if I was given the operand register values but because I wasn't, I didn't know if the $s1 registers current value held any merit. Thank you greatly for the clarification.

Comment: As a follow up, is it possible to deduce those register values if we're also given the answer? For example, the answer to this specific problem is supposed to be 0x0000ff3a. Given that hex value along with the $s1 register before contents, is there any way to deduce the values of the other two registers from those two pieces of data?

Comment: @AnthonyBunker: no, with only 32 bits of information, you can't uniquely determine *both* 32-bit inputs (64 bits of information).  You can come up with possible inputs, but they're not uniquely determined.  e.g. given result = `9`, was it `-3 + 12`, `12 + (-3)`, `5+4`, or what?  The value of `$s1` *before* this instruction runs doesn't give you *any* information about the inputs, like I already said.  Unless there was actually a sequence of multiple instructions and `$s1` was computed earlier, then you could work backwards and maybe learn something if you know what computed `$s1`.